# How do I access FeedEk's callback or success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss, feed

I am using FeedEk to load various Rss Feeds, then attempting to declare the feeds in an array, and if one feed produces no results, switch to the next feed array element.  I am having trouble loading the results of FeedEk into a variable, to validate for content.

I have tried loading the results into a hidden div, then validating the hidden div and passing the content into the live view.  Couldn't get that working so I tried accessing a success or callback function, but that didn't work either.  I can't find any documentation for a callback or this problem, so here I am.

Code:

```
    $('#divRss').FeedEk({
        FeedUrl :  "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss",
        callback: function(){
            alert("done");
        }
     });
```

This is my attempt to load the results into a hidden div first, then transpose it to a visible div:

```
    $('#rssload').FeedEk({
         FeedUrl : feeds[1]
    });
    var tryFeed = $('#rssload').html();
    $('#divRss').html(tryFeed);
```

I know that the problem isn't in the array declaration, as I am able to display the results directly using $('#divRss').FeedEk({FeedUrl : feeds[1]});

**A more direct version of the question:
How can I validate the results of FeedEk, to ensure content is returned prior to displaying the content?**

If anyone is familiar with FeedEk.js, or knows a RSS plugin that suits this purpose better, I would very much like to hear it!  Thanks in advance, and I'll provide more details if needed.

Comment: I'm not sure about how FeedEk works, but it actually uses the [Google Feed API][1] and you should maybe look at the underlying to build what you're trying to build, as it's realtively easy with the Google Feed API to know about a feed that fails to load.


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/feed/

Comment: Thank you for the Google API tip.  This led me down the path to a solution.  Wish I could mark this as the answer.

Comment: Do you mind putting the answer (what you did to solve) to this question? I am also trying to figure out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ended up re-writing the whole thing in PHP, using direct access to Google's Feed API.  I never figured out how to work with FeedEk.  Maybe some of my PHP code could help you?